# How can I implement Interceptor with this axios code

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, axios

I am posting to an api using Axios (and Vue.js). I have added a small condition in **catch** which checks the response data and compares it.

Is there a better way to approach this, as I can imagine this will grow and become harder to maintain. How can I implement interceptor with this example? Ideally I want to handle server error responses better with less code blocks.

```
axios
          .post("/api/apipathwillgohere", formData)
          .then(function(response) {
            self.sucessfulServerResponse = response.data.message;
            window.localStorage.clear();
            // console.log(response.data);
            if (response.data.success == true) {
              // localStorage.email = response.data.email;
              location.reload();
            } else {
              self.errorMessage = response.data.error;
              self.submitClicked = false;
              console.log(response.data.error);
            }
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            // If BackEnd refresh flag is true, then refresh page
            if (
              error.response.data.data.refresh == true ||
              error.response.data.data.message == "Token mismatch"
            ) {
              self.submitClicked = true;
              location.reload();
            }

            self.submitClicked = false;
            self.serverError = getErrorMessage(error);

            //helper to get a displayable message to the user
            function getErrorMessage(error) {
              let responseBody;
              responseBody = error.response;
              if (!responseBody) {
                responseBody = error;
              } else {
                responseBody = error.response.data || responseBody;
              }
              return responseBody.message || JSON.stringify(responseBody);
            }
          })
          .then(() => {
            self.status = "";
          });
```

Comment: Could always use the transform response section of the config and do the checks there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a logic you would like to run on every request, you should use an interceptor (check interceptors section in axios [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios). This is especially useful for auth situations, for instance if your api returns token invalid, you should redirect user to login page.